# Powering 4 modulated IR LEDs through transistor

Tags: transistors, infrared, modulation, darlington

I've done some research but can't seem to find an answer to my specific problem.

I'm using an Arduino as a beam-break sensor. In order to do that it modulates the IR LED at 38kHz by code and listens for this signal on the sensor pin.
Now, I want to increase the range of this system to 15m using a retroreflector on the other side. In order to do that I need more power on the LEDs than the 20mA the Arduino can output.

As I understand it I will need a transistor to do this.

I have ordered [these LEDs](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1545/0900766b81545a2c.pdf)

And these [TIP120 transistors](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1385/0900766b813859d2.pdf)

Will I be able to accomplish having 4 LEDs running through this transistor at 100mAh each and then have the Arduino modulate the transistor at 38kHz so the combined output of all LEDs is modulated?

I already have a 12v power supply in place so that will be the supply voltage for the system.

Comment: IR LEDs usually only drop about 1.5V.  So you could just wire 4 in series, and select an appropriate current limiting resostor.

Comment: I was thinking that as well. My problem, however, is if I understand the use of the transistor correctly and if I need anything else for this to work

Comment: You will also need a couple of resistors.  Driving a transistor from an Arduino is such a common thing, you can just Google it.  Find an example of "low side switching".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the transistor and LEDS, you will need a couple of resistors.  It will be easiest to wire the diodes in series, with one resistor for current limiting.  you should also add a resistor before the base of the transistor.

See [this Stack Exchange answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/303148/high-side-or-low-side-led-driver-with-npn-bjt-which-is-better) for an example.  Circuit A - "low side switching" - is almost certainly better.